# How to convert calculated properties (that involve calling other methods) into Django generated fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I have this following model:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=19,
        decimal_places=4,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    
    @property
    def price_in_cents(self):
        return round(self.price * 100)
    
    @property
    def has_expired(self):
        if self.expiry_date:
            return date.today() > self.expiry_date.date()
        else:
            return False
```

So two fields, and two other properties that rely on these two fields to generate an output. I'm trying to convert these fields into generated fields (for Django 5). My first understanding was simply just putting in the property function in the expression, so something like this:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=19,
        decimal_places=4,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    price_in_cents = models.GeneratedField(
        expression=round(F("price") * 100),
        output_field=models.BigIntegerField(),
        db_persist=True,
    )
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    
    @property
    def has_expired(self):
        if self.expiry_date:
            return date.today() > self.expiry_date.date()
        else:
            return False
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work, and I get the following error:

> TypeError: type CombinedExpression doesn't define **round** method

Going by this, I assume I won't be able to simply convert the second property either. So how would this actually work? Is there a resource to help me convert these Python functions (properties) into valid expressions?

Comment: It has to be database query expression not as in calculated property just round function https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use database query function `Round`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Round
# Create your models here.


class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=19,
        decimal_places=4,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    price_in_cents = models.GeneratedField(
        expression=Round(F("price") * 100),
        output_field=models.BigIntegerField(),
        db_persist=True,
    )
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    
    @property
    def has_expired(self):
        if self.expiry_date:
            return date.today() > self.expiry_date.date()
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Oh awesome. How would you convert the `has_expired` property?

Comment: @darkhorse: you probably can't since the computation should be determinstic, but it depends on the current date, which is not deterministic. It would also mean the database would actively refresh every day.

Answer (score 1):

[`GeneratedField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.GeneratedField.expression) expression requires Query expression [`Expression`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/expressions/#expression-api)

therefore you should use Database function  [Round](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#round) instead

```
price_in_cents = models.GeneratedField(
    expression=Round(F("price") * 100),
    output_field=models.BigIntegerField(),
    db_persist=True,
)
```

Comment: Oh awesome. How would you convert the `has_expired` property?

Comment: generation expression cannot use immutable functions if your db is PostgreSQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html